# How can I access the properties of objects inside an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Aaron Hillegass (Exercise of Part 17).

Problem: In my loop, I would like it to log the values for each of the 3 `StockHolding` objects, but right now it's only logging the values for `DHL`. How can I get my loop to log the values for the other 2 objects?

Thank you!

P.S. StockHolding.h и StockHolding.m are all right.

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
import "StockHolding.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {

    StockHolding *DHL = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [DHL setPurchaseSharePrice:345.67];
    [DHL setNumberOfShares:23];
    [DHL setCurrentSharePrice:389.23];

    StockHolding *Sony = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [Sony setPurchaseSharePrice:587.12];
    [Sony setNumberOfShares:14];
    [Sony setCurrentSharePrice:603.81];

    StockHolding *EPAM = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [EPAM setPurchaseSharePrice:178.45];
    [EPAM setNumberOfShares:35];
    [EPAM setCurrentSharePrice:190.64];

    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, nil];

    for (NSObject *n in result) {
    NSLog(@"Purchase for: %f\nNumber of shares: %d\nCurrent share price: %f\nCost,$: %f\nValue,$: %f\n", DHL.purchaseSharePrice, DHL.numberOfShares, DHL.currentSharePrice, DHL.costInDollars, DHL.valueInDollars);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Problem solved:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {


    StockHolding *DHL = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [DHL setNameOfShare:@"DHL"];
    [DHL setPurchaseSharePrice:345.67];
    [DHL setNumberOfShares:23];
    [DHL setCurrentSharePrice:389.23];

    StockHolding *Sony = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [Sony setNameOfShare:@"Sony"];
    [Sony setPurchaseSharePrice:587.12];
    [Sony setNumberOfShares:14];
    [Sony setCurrentSharePrice:603.81];

    StockHolding *EPAM = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    [EPAM setNameOfShare:@"EPAM"];
    [EPAM setPurchaseSharePrice:178.45];
    [EPAM setNumberOfShares:35];
    [EPAM setCurrentSharePrice:190.64];

    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, nil];

    for (StockHolding *n in result) {
    NSLog(@"\nName: %@\nPurchase for: %.2f\nNumber of shares: %lu\nCurrent share price: %.2f\nCost,$: %.2f\nValue,$: %.2f\n", n.nameOfShare, n.purchaseSharePrice, n.numberOfShares, n.currentSharePrice, n.costInDollars, n.valueInDollars);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

There is another option:

```
[result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(StockHolding *DHL, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"\nName: %@\nPurchase for: %.2fl\nNumber of shares: %lu\nCurrent share price: %.2fl\nCost,$: %.2fl\nValue,$: %.2fl\n", DHL.nameOfShare, DHL.purchaseSharePrice, (unsigned long)DHL.numberOfShares, DHL.currentSharePrice, DHL.costInDollars, DHL.valueInDollars);
}];
```

Thanks you all!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you need help with? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: `for (StockHolding *aStockHolding in result){NSLog@(..., aStockHolding.purchaseSharePrice,...}` ?

Comment: I need to make result with description of each element of array "result", which contains 3 objects. To display this information I use get methods, but I don't know how I may automate this process for each object in NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like the for loop at the end of your code is wrong. I imagine you're trying to run the NSLog for each of the three `StockHolding` variables? The way you have it written, it's just going to repeat the values for DHL 3 times.

Try this instead:

```
for (StockHolding *n in result) {
    NSLog(@"Purchase for: %f\nNumber of shares: %d\nCurrent share price: %f\nCost,$: %f\nValue,$: %f\n", 
           n.purchaseSharePrice, 
           n.numberOfShares, 
           n.currentSharePrice, 
           n.costInDollars, 
           n.valueInDollars);
}
```

Comment: I tried. Error: property 'purchaseSharePrice' not found on object of type 'NSObject'

Comment: In your `for` statement, you should be using `StockHolding *n` instead of `NSObject *n`.

Comment: Big thanks! Also i found alternative variation:
`
[result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(StockHolding *DHL, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"\nName: %@\nPurchase for: %.2fl\nNumber of shares: %lu\nCurrent share price: %.2fl\nCost,$: %.2fl\nValue,$: %.2fl\n", DHL.nameOfShare, DHL.purchaseSharePrice, (unsigned long)DHL.numberOfShares, DHL.currentSharePrice, DHL.costInDollars, DHL.valueInDollars);
        }];`

Comment: Yes, that works too, but I would recommend giving your variables more meaningful names. You've already declared `DHL` as a specific instance of `StockHolding`, and it's confusing when you reuse that name as a placeholder in your loop.

Comment: No Problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: OK, I'm still just learning ;)